# How do I save API data into a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have extracted some data from an API:

```
response = requests.get("https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/2019-09-05/2019-09-06")
```

How do I convert/save the results into a `pandas` DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do a [`read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) directly to read:

```
api=r'https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/2019-09-05/2019-09-06'
df=pd.read_json(api,orient='split')
print(df.head())
```

---

```
                from                 to  \
0  2019-09-04T23:30Z  2019-09-05T00:00Z   
1  2019-09-05T00:00Z  2019-09-05T00:30Z   
2  2019-09-05T00:30Z  2019-09-05T01:00Z   
3  2019-09-05T01:00Z  2019-09-05T01:30Z   
4  2019-09-05T01:30Z  2019-09-05T02:00Z   

                                         intensity  
0   {'forecast': 87, 'actual': 80, 'index': 'low'}  
1   {'forecast': 85, 'actual': 81, 'index': 'low'}  
2   {'forecast': 91, 'actual': 83, 'index': 'low'}  
3   {'forecast': 97, 'actual': 82, 'index': 'low'}  
4  {'forecast': 100, 'actual': 83, 'index': 'low'}
```

---

Also if you want to expand the dict in the last column into separate series, use:

```
final=df.assign(**pd.DataFrame(df.pop('intensity').tolist()))
print(final.head())
```

---

```
                from                 to  forecast  actual index
0  2019-09-04T23:30Z  2019-09-05T00:00Z        87      80   low
1  2019-09-05T00:00Z  2019-09-05T00:30Z        85      81   low
2  2019-09-05T00:30Z  2019-09-05T01:00Z        91      83   low
3  2019-09-05T01:00Z  2019-09-05T01:30Z        97      82   low
4  2019-09-05T01:30Z  2019-09-05T02:00Z       100      83   low
```

Comment: I really like this solution.  Would you elaborate on what the two asterisks do here `final=df.assign(**pd.DataFrame(df.pop('intensity').tolist()))`?

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy you can think of it as `pd.concat` on `axis=1` , from the docs of `df.assign` : `**kwargs : dict of {str: callable or Series}
    The column names are keywords. If the values are
    callable, they are computed on the DataFrame and
    assigned to the new columns.` Please consider an upvote and accept the solution if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `response.json()` to get the output as a dictionary, then convert it to a pandas DataFrame using `from_dict()`.

```
p = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response.json()['data'])
```